# Delayed databinding

Tags: winforms, data-binding, .net-3.5

I have a combo box and a label that are linked together with data binding.

[image]

When I change the selection in the combo box, the label doesn't show any change until I focus away from the combo box.

I would like to instead have the label show the change as soon as the user clicks on a different selection in the combo box.

Is there a solution without having to manually write a callback to the combobox SelectedValueChanged event?

I am trying to see what I can do with data binding in .NET 3.5 land.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try updating the binding value on the SelectedIndexChanged event:

```
comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += (cb, cbArgs) => {
                                    comboBox1.DataBindings[0].WriteValue();
                                  };
```

Comment: Thanks. This works, but I'm disappointed it takes 6 lines of code to set up data binding for this one object. This seems like more code than the manual process.

Comment: @micahhoover It's one of the typical knocks against WinForms from the WPF crowd.

Comment: Ah. I guess that's the best I can do.